# Automorphism group of $\mathbf{C}$ over $\overline{\mathbf{Q}}$

Tags: nt.number-theory, galois-theory, number-fields, transcendental-number-theory, galois-groups

Choose an embedding $\overline{\mathbf{Q}}\rightarrow \mathbf{C}$ from an algebraic closure of the field of rationals to the field of complex numbers.

**Question 1:** Is it true that $\mathbf{C}$ is isomorphic to $\overline{\mathbf{Q}}(T_{i\in I})$ a pure transcendental extension of degree the cardinality of some uncountable set $I$ ?

**Question 2** Is there a concrete description of the (profinite ?) group $\mathrm{Aut}_{\overline{\mathbf{Q}}}(\mathbf{C})$ ?

Comment: For your question question 1: no this field is never algebraically closed ($T_i$ cannot have a square root).

Comment: Question 2. Without Choice, the group is trivial. With Choice, the group is huge but there is not a concrete description of single element (otherwise you wouldn't need Choice to show it exists).

Comment: @SimonHenry thanks for your remark, you are right!

Comment: @zeno What do you mean by "Choice" ?

Comment: "Choice" means the Axiom of Choice.  The only non-trivial automorphism of $\mathbf C$ that you can prove exists (without using AC) is complex conjugation.  And that does not fix all algebraic numbers.

Comment: @zeno It may look pedantic, but I believe one should say that "without choice, the group may be trivial". Does one know what this group may look like without assuming choice?

Comment: @Zeno, the fact that without choice it is not possible to construct a single automorphism of $\mathbb{C}$ is not enough to conclude that it is not possible to give an explicit description of the group up to isomorphism: indeed, there could be an explicit description of the group, but you would need the axiom of choice to construct the action of the group on $\mathbb{C}$. Typically assuming choice, $\mathbb{C}$ is isomorphic to the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}[X_i]$ and you cannot exclude that for this field there is interesting automorphisms even without choice.

Comment: I believe without choice, the group is trivial, as I stated. It's known that all automorphisms  of the complex numbers are nonmeasurable (other than 1 and complex conjugation), and I believe that without Choice all functions are measurable.

Comment: @zeno: Your statements seem a bit imprecise to me. What do you mean precisely by "without choice"? You just mean that it fails, right? But the axiom of choice could be fine when applied to sets which inject into the complexes and could only start failing for much larger sets like what you get if you iterate the power set axiom on the complexes countably infinitely many times. If this happened then we are "without Choice" but most statements about the reals or complexes which require choice will still be true because enough choice will still work and this is all you need.