# complex numbers over algebraic numbers, continuous cohomology

Tags: nt.number-theory, galois-theory, galois-cohomology

This question is related to [this one](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/235933/automorphism-group-of-mathbfc-over-overline-mathbfq). Choose an embedding $\overline{\mathbf{Q}}\rightarrow \mathbf{C}$ from the algebraic closure of the field of rational numbers to the field of complex numbers. Is it realistic to say some thing about $H_{cont}^{\ast}(Aut_{\overline{\mathbf{Q}}}(\mathbf{C}),A)$ the continuous cohomology of the group of field automorphisms of $\mathbf{C}$ over $\overline{\mathbf{Q}}$ ?

$A$ is a finite $Aut_{\overline{\mathbf{Q}}}(\mathbf{C})$-module with the trivial action.

Comment: What do you mean by "continuous"?

Comment: @LaurentMoret-Bailly I see $Aut_{\overline{Q}}(C)$ as a profinite group... Am I wrong ?

Comment: No, this group is not profinite since complex numbers are not algebraic over rationals (and so, cannot be presented as the union of finite degree Galois extensions of $\overline{\mathbf{Q}}$).